# doctrine get count with criteria on a many-to-many self-referencing relation

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user which can have many friends. Means the relation is self-referencing.
I now need the count of my friends friends according to their gender. I came up with the following solution so far.

My User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendsOf")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="map_user_friend",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $friends;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="friends")
     */
    private $friendsOf;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $gender;

    // other fields ...

}
```

My UserRepository has the following method:

```
public function getFriendsQuery(User $user)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u as user, COUNT(DISTINCT mf.id) as male_friends, COUNT(DISTINCT ff.id) as female_friends')
        ->from('Oneup\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'mf', 'with', 'mf.gender = :gender')->setParameter('gender', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'ff', 'with', 'ff.gender = :gender')->setParameter('gender', 'w')
        ->where('f = :user')->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->groupBy('u.id')
    ;
}
```

In the controller I now dump the SQL first by `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());` which returns

```
SELECT u0_.username AS username0,
       u0_.username_canonical AS username_canonical1,
       -- ... --
       u0_.gender AS gender19,
       -- ... --
       COUNT(DISTINCT u1_.id) AS sclr32,
       COUNT(DISTINCT u2_.id) AS sclr33
FROM users u0_
LEFT JOIN map_user_friend m4_ ON u0_.id = m4_.friend_id
LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = m4_.user_id
LEFT JOIN map_user_friend m5_ ON u0_.id = m5_.friend_id
LEFT JOIN users u1_ ON u1_.id = m5_.user_id
AND (u1_.gender = ?)
LEFT JOIN map_user_friend m6_ ON u0_.id = m6_.friend_id
LEFT JOIN users u2_ ON u2_.id = m6_.user_id
AND (u2_.gender = ?)
WHERE u3_.id = ?
GROUP BY u0_.id
```

Parameters are `m` for male, `f` for female and `21` for the current user. Now follows the weird behavior. `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($qb->getQuery()->execute());` returns me

```
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'Oneup\UserBundle\Entity\User' (length=28)
      'male_friends' => string '2' (length=1)
      'female_friends' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 =>
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'Oneup\UserBundle\Entity\User' (length=28)
      'male_friends' => string '0' (length=1)
      'female_friends' => string '0' (length=1)
```

If I'm executing the query straight in mysql I get an other count:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| username0    | sclr32 (male)   | sclr33 (female) |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| foobar12     | 1               | 2               |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| foobar2      | 2               | 0               |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

which is correct. Is this a doctrine bug, or am I just doing it plain wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is me, but I have some difficulties in comparing the result from the raw sql query a the one from Doctrine. Maybe because I don't understand what is the input, the id of the entities and so on! Please, can you explain the input/output better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the error was on the parameters in the Repository

```
   ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'mf', 'with', 'mf.gender = :gender')->setParameter('gender', 'm')
   ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'ff', 'with', 'ff.gender = :gender')->setParameter('gender', 'w')
```

was wrong. doctrine takes the second value for both entries.

```
   ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'mf', 'with', 'mf.gender = :male')->setParameter('male', 'm')
   ->leftJoin('u.friendsOf', 'ff', 'with', 'ff.gender = :female')->setParameter('female', 'w')
```